# How to change status "Developer Action Needed" in In-App Purchase Feature

Tags: iphone

My app was rejected earlier and I uploaded it again after resolving issues. I have implemented the In App Purchase feature in the app, but now its status is **Developer Action Needed** and I can see "Rejected" before the language I had selected to display the name of the app. I can't attach the screen shot as my reputation is just 9. So please let me know how to change this status to "Waiting For Review". What I should do?

Comment: Btw its not ranking, its reputation. A rank 9 on SO is equal to Admin and can cut, copy, paste and do almost everything. :-)

Comment: @Praveen: Thanks for telling me, I knew it :-) just wrote that in a  hurry!

Comment: :-). Anyways i hope you get an answer here. In worst case you can reject your binary and upload it all over again. It takes same amount of time for review.

Comment: I changed my title and description—that worked.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Do you meant you are seeing "Developer Action Needed" in your In app purchase item ? If yes then try to change price range of your In app purchase and save it and again change it to original one. I guess this will affect to take it in review.

If this is not working Delete your language you added and add it again and Also make sure you have checked "Clear for Sale" and upload a screenshot.

Comment: @Deeps: Thanks, It worked but still I can see the "PENDING" written before the Language I added but the status is now "waiting For Review", Why it is showing me "PENDING" before the Languages?

Comment: Great It worked. You added multiple languages in In app purchase items?

Comment: @Deeps: one is English and other is Italian but now I want to delete "Italian" but it says "Failed to delete item. Please try again.". I tried again and again but same response. I think there is some error in Apple Management for Languages

Comment: Yeah. They have lots of loop hole in the In app purchase Items. I faced lots of issues with no reason some times and it worked later. So wait for some time and they try again.

Comment: Also, It this help and worked please mark it as Answer so others can follow this steps if they have same issue. Thanks

Comment: @Deeps: sure Deeps, let me gain 15 reputation only after that I can accept your answer, and I will.

Comment: I guess you don't need 15 reputations. I just come to know that you can mark answer after 15 mins. Not sure though.

Comment: I did same but my in app purchases are in "waiting for review", any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Can we reject their app store, so they fix all their bugs too?

Comment: My subscriptions was apprved , i add additional information about subcriptions , see review notes beside screen schot image

Answer (score 82):

Simply edit the description by clicking on the language name next to the REJECTED marker.  Add a space at the end of the Display Description (only shown to Apple) if you don't want to change anything.  After saving, the REjECTED marker will change to PENDING and you'll be back in business.

Comment: That one helped me. Stupid Apple systems - they just should have a button: re-submit or so...

Comment: I tried by change name, description as well as by remove the language and add it again but again apple review make it "Developer Action needed".

Comment: I had to add a space in the middle of the description, save, remove the space, save again and then it fixed all 3 in app purchases I had, even though I only did this to ONE description.

Comment: You're a star! This is indeed a very awkward user interface from Apple.

Answer (score 16):

i found one HACK to change "Developer action needed".

- Open subscription where "Submit for Review" is disabled and status is Developer action Needed.
- Reload the page for 1-2 seconds "Submit for Review" will be enabled press it quickly.
- And your subscription will get subbmit.

Comment: This works - however you first have to edit your rejected localization, change it slightly so that the "Save" button becomes enabled. Once saved, change it back to what it was. Nor reload the page and click on "Submit for Review" before it becomes disabled.

Comment: Here is how it's done (you need to click fast after reloading) https://youtu.be/865YTXKl0-w

Answer (score 7):

Next time all you have to do is edit the name by clicking on the Language. Change the name of the application. Save it once done and can revert back to the old application name.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having this issue, try the same method as described but instead uncheck the "Cleared for sale", save, check "Cleared for sale" and save again. Then re-load the page and quickly press "Submit for review" before its grayed-out. Hope it helps someone who lost the same amount of hair as us.

Comment: This is what worked for me.  See this video: https://youtu.be/865YTXKl0-w

I am pretty sure it's a recent bug with Apple (August 2022) that you need to click faster than the button going disabled.

Comment: We spoke with Apple Dev Support about this, if anyone has the same issue, please record your screen and send in a formal bug report. According to them, this has not been a problem for about 4 years. I had trouble convincing them that it’s alive again.

Answer (score 1):

No need to delete the language you added, after your item review is rejected. Just click the rejected item, and make a little change, and then save it, and the status will be changed from  "REJECTED" to "PENDING" to wait for review again.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, do nothing with this. Just upload a new build/binary to itunes coonect and wait for review. They will automatically care about your in app purchases.

Comment: Yeah, I guess so, but making it to be shown as "Waiting for Review" feels much better than "Developer Action Needed".. Just in case. XD

Comment: Is it ok if I add binary in "external testing review" ?

Comment: This may have used to be the case, but my most recent In-App Purchase didn't get switched from rejected to Ready for Sale even after Apple approved my new binary.  As suggested below, I changed the Description and clicked Save, now it says waiting for review.   Hopefully they review quickly b/c right now i'm getting errors if users try to buy the rejected in app purchase subscription and it shows null for the price!

Comment: I can confirm that this solution didn't work now in August 2022.  I uploaded a new build/binary/version.  It got approved, but the IAPs didn't.

Answer (score 1):

It's September 2022 and the common solution of "add a character to description, save, remove that, save again" wasn't working for us.

### Our Situation

1. It was the first version we added IAP (Subscription)
2. The app itself got approved and released
3. The IAPs went to Rejected/Developer Action Needed over localization. We didn't get informed of that. (oops!) No further detail on "why" was provided.

### Our tries

1. We added the subscription duration to the product name (there is no guideline on why it's rejected and what it should be), and
2. We brought the "Restore Purchases" button to the same place that the packages are listed.
3. The IAP was in the same "**Developer Action Needed**" state while the localization was in "Prepare for Submission".  However, the "Submit for Review" button was grayed out, constantly. So there was absolutely nothing that we could do there.
4. We thought another App review would fix it.  Although we were unable to [attach](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev1986a0e5c) the IAPs to the new version, we uploaded a new binary/version anyway and asked for expedited review. The new version went through and got approved, but IAPs were still in this state!

### What worked

1. We saw that if we add a new plan (just test) we can attach it to a new version.  So one option was to create new plans and attach them to a new binary.  But since the product_IDs were already baked into our systems, we didn't want to create new ones and change them everywhere.
2. Desperately searching, I found [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516301/how-to-change-status-developer-action-needed-in-in-app-purchase-feature#comment129569886_73045954) from [Ondrej Kvasnovsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/931428/ondrej-kvasnovsky) that in a 9-second video, changed our life! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=865YTXKl0-w
   This magic is actually working and now our IAPs are in "Waiting for Review"!

[image]