# Why my app's In-App-Purchase status change to 'Developer Action Needed' while the app's status still In Review?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

Five days ago，my app's status change to ‘In Review’, I checked the IAP items，their status also changed to ‘In Review’.But yesterday I found the app's status still In Review,The IAP items changed to ‘Developer Action Needed’,and the resolution center has no messge tell me why this happened.
Can anybody tell me why this happened and what should I do?[My app's current status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPZlL.png)

[In-App-Purchase items status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFYgc.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516301/how-to-change-status-developer-action-needed-in-in-app-purchase-feature

Comment: If a app rejected by apple,they will tell  you the reason and what to do next in resolution center,But my app's status is still In Review.