# App review unable to locate Auto renewing subscriptions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, auto-renewing

I'm trying to release a new version of an existing app to the app store. The app already has consumable IAP's and the new version is implementing Auto renewing subscriptions.

When i submitted the new version of the app to review i had already linked the IAP's to the new binary.

The first time, the IAP's got rejecting due to metadata issues and the IAP's went into the "Developer action needed" state. After this i included the metadata they asked for and i made a trivial change to the localized descriptions, which caused the IAP's to go into the "Waiting for review" state.

These ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45492991/cannot-re-add-in-app-purchase-to-app-after-rejection-in-itunesconnect), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516301/how-to-change-status-developer-action-needed-in-in-app-purchase-feature)) stackoverflow posts state that i should resubmit the binary for review again. However when i did that, the reviewer was not able to locate the IAP's in the app so i got rejected again due to "Performance: App Completeness". He attached a screenshot where the new subscriptions weren't loaded with the other IAP's, so the subscriptions were in fact not visible during review. The same build works and loads the products correctly in TestFlight so i don't understand what is causing the issue.

I have tried submitting for review again with the same result.

The reviewer mentioned the auto renewing subscriptions explicitly by their reference names, so they must be linked to the binary. He just wasn't able to see them...

Has anyone experienced anything like this? Am i maybe missing something?

Hope you guys can help! :)